# Workaround to Hero Card as attachment markdown formatting?

Tags: botframework

I know that markdown is supported on the HeroCard "text" field value, even though I couldn't make it work(Tested on MSTeams):

[image]

Code

```
this.bot.dialog("sendCard", (session, args, next) => {
    session.sendTyping();
    const card = new builder.HeroCard(session);

    card.title("Title");
    card.subtitle("Subtitle");
    card.text("This is some *mardown* text! \n\n - one \n\n - two");

    const msg = new builder.Message(session);

    msg.textFormat("markdown");
    msg.attachments([
        card,
    ]);
    session.endDialog(msg);
});
```

I am wondering how can I achieve this formatting(From mailclark bot in MSTeams):

[image]

As you can see, it is a carousel of what I think it might be HeroCards, but they are formatted with **bold, code and unordered lists on new paragraphs**.

It seems to be a known issue that message attachments do not receive formatting, but **how could the mailclark guys achieve it**?

---

Edit:
Unordered list example:
[image]

Bold and code example:
[image]

Comment: Check this link out: https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here/wiki/Markdown-Cheatsheet You may get some closure

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Hero Cards eventually will be convert to Rich Card send to user from bot, and from MS Teams documents at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-conversations#formatting-text-content:

> Microsoft Teams supports a subset of Markdown and XML (HTML) formatting tags.
>
> Rich cards do not support Markdown or table formatting

So in MS Teams channel, markdown formatting is only supported in text only message, however, we can leverage `HTML` tags in Rich Card.

Please consider following code snippet:

```
bot.dialog('/', function (session) {
    const card = new builder.HeroCard(session);
    card.title("Type your question to our support team here");
    card.subtitle("Or, click the ◀▶ arrows for a series of how-tos");
    card.images([builder.CardImage.create(session,"<image url>")])
    card.text("<p>This is some <i>mardown</i> <b>text</b>!</p> <ul><li><b>one</b></li><li><code>two</code></li></ul>")
    const msg = new builder.Message(session);
    msg.attachmentLayout(builder.AttachmentLayout.carousel);
    msg.attachments([
        card,card,card
    ]).toMessage();
    session.send(msg);
    session.endDialog("This is some *mardown* **text**! \n\n - **one** \n\n - `two`");
});
```

This shows in MS Teams as following:
[image]

Comment: Nice! It worked, I saw somewhere on their doccumentation that html(xml markup) was only available on skype so I tried not to use it, but this got it solved, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

MailClark here. You're right: it's a carousel of Hero Cards.

As Gary said, it's mostly simple HTML with a few `<code>` and `<strong>` tags.

But this is the real secret: the list is not HTML it's just regular text and the 3 lines are starting with a good old bullet character: `•` (we didn't like the style produced by `<ul><li>`).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I was trying not to use html since I read that it only worked on skype so I kept trying not to use it